# Comment History in Sales Quote Admin view

Tags: quote, cloud

In magento backend sales qoute admin panel , the history and comemnt tab not able to load.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nlan.png

Comment: please check php_error.log and magento log

Comment: [2022-08-18T05:59:33.086870+00:00] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'customer.group.extra.data' tries to reorder itself towards 'negotiable.quote.info.extra.container', but their parents are different: 'negotiable.quote.info.extra.container' and 'negotiable.quote.info' respectively. [] []
[2022-08-18T05:59:33.087058+00:00] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []

Answer (score 0):

Please open the inspect window on that page.
I think there's a jquery error.
Please attach it or fix it.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1omUo6_xRLFCCxulDyj86fkFCnT-9euBz/view?usp=sharing

I am getting this error dom loading failed